# Volume Extremely Low on built-in card but works on bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, intel, alienware

I have seen similar issues described before, but it is not a volume control issue : the audio coming out of my built-in soundcard, even when the volume is set to 150% everywhere, is still about 2-5% of what it *should* be, and cannot be raised further. It's also distorted.

> **This is not a volume control issue. It's not fixed by raising volume in alsamixer and pavucontrol. It's not fixed by boosting to 150% volume. It is NOT a volume issue!**

Here's what I have confirmed:

**alsamixer volume is 100%**:

[image: alsa mixer 100% volume]

**pavucontrol is boosted to 150%** and the correct device and output are selected. *The meter displays proper expected volumes*, in the screenshot I'm playing some random youtube video and it goes up to full blue on the meter:
[image]

**I've tried 2 different outputs**: both the built-in speaker output, and the front panel output, both are detected as "plugged in" or "unplugged" depending on whether I have speakers or a headset connected on either jacks, so it's the *right* one.

Other important points:

- Volume is fine in windows, as expected
- Adding a bluetooth device (headphones) works as expected, so it's not a general sound issue, it's directly related to the hardware itself
- It's been happening for many versions, I regularly try to see if Ubuntu will "just work" and it never really does, but this time with Wubuntu it was a lot better except for this persistent audio issue.
- I recall specifically in the past having checked whether the sound card was supposed to be supported, and canonical indicated 100% compatibility, so this shouldn't be a problem. It's Intel/Creative, not exactly a weird unknown brand.